# Nginx rewrite not working at all

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to set up a Piwigo to run on Nginx but I got into some issues with links that should contain and index.php like this:
**foto.domain.net/index.php/category/3**

It seems like a simple task, rewriting **/index/category/3** to **/index.php/category/3**, but no matter what I write in those rewrites, I end up with a 404 error and a never changing error log entry that looks like this:

```
open() "/srv/http/foto/index/category/3" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 94.242.246.23, server: ~^(?<prefix>www)?\.?(?<subdomain>[a-z]+)?\.domain\.net$, request: "GET /index/category/3 HTTP/1.1", host: "foto.domain.net", referrer: "http://foto.domain.net/"
```

The error log looks the same even if I add junk to the rewrite line such as:

```
rewrite ^/index((/|$).*)$ /JUNK_index.php$1 last;
```

So the rewrite part is faulty, somehow but I can't figure it out...

```html
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.net;
    return       301 $scheme://www.domain.net$request_uri;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name "~^(?<prefix>www)?\.?(?<subdomain>[a-z]+)?\.domain\.net$";
 root /srv/http/$subdomain;

 location @rewrites {
     rewrite ^/picture((/|$).*)$ /picture.php$1 last;
     rewrite ^/index((/|$).*)$ /index.php$1 last;
     # The following is needed for batch operations which use i.php
     rewrite ^/i((/|$).*)$ /i.php$1 last;
 }

 location /$subdomain {
     index index.php index.html;
     try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ @rewrites;
 }
 
 location ~ ^(?<script_name>.+?\.php)(?<path_info>/.*)?$ {
     try_files $script_name = 404;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it in the end after many changes. The most important one was moving the rewrites in a location / {} block because the try_files ... @rewrites; didn't work for me at all.

Comment: `location /$subdomain` is nonsense. You can't use variables in location. It matches literally to `/$subdomain` request, which is not what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

In general terms, as a checklist:

- make sure the target/landing URI exists
- this should have output "rewrite": nginx 2>&1 | grep -i -o rewrite
- check your error and access log